# MySQL don't read second OR condition if the first one is true

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-null

I'm trying to make an SQL-statement where I get the parameters from c# code.
The problem is that some of the parameters can be 'null'. But in MySQL I can't properly read `WHERE column=NULL` and I can only do `WHERE column IS NULL`.

So I was trying to make the statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column=param #(param given from C#)
OR column IS param
```

I thought this would work fine because MySQL shouldn't care about the second condition if the first one is already true (like Python). And it does work when param is null. But there's an error when param is a string because then MySQL reads: `WHERE column IS 'string'`.

**Is there a way to solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `<=>`, the [`null`-safe equality operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
WHERE column <=> param
```

Basically, `NULL <=> NULL` is true, while `NULL = NULL` is undefined.

Note that you should be properly passing your parameter to the query, using a prepared statement. String `'null'` is not the same thing as a `null` value.